# php -v and phpinfo versions are different

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

today I changed from php7.2 to 7.0 for testing. Then I tried to change back to 7.2 and `php -v` outputs

> PHP 7.2.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2018 14:59:25) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

and `phpinfo();` outputs

[image]

Comment: It seems like phpinfo and your question didn't get submitted.

Comment: did you restart apache after switching your PHP version?

Comment: @RamyNasr I use nginx, and yes, i restarted it

Comment: Your command line and HTTP server are using different versions of PHP, ie you have multiple versions installed

Comment: @Phill I'm gonna reinstall the VPS

Answer (score 0):

If you run `php -v` this print the version of `php-cli`.

If run `phpinfo();` into a php file, you print the version of `php-fpm`.

`php-fpm` is used by your web server(`nginx`, `apache`) to process the `.php`, while `php-cli` is used for console commands.